# Can't sum cells that reference cells of another worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

On my first worksheet I have a column of cells that reference cells in a second  worksheet. They correctly display as numbers on worksheet 1. However, when I try to sum this column, I get a result of 0. I think I need to convert the display results to actual numerical values in worksheet 1. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: More information would help.  1) the exact formulas you are using. 2) photos of your worksheet posted to imugr then linked here.

Comment: Thanks - here is a view of the formulas and worksheet data: http://imgur.com/gallery/aTXl8MJ

Comment: If the numbers are truly in D10:D12 then is should work,  Try hitting F9 to see if the sheet needs to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps to try with questions mixed in.

1) Update your question.

2) Check the format of the cells on Worksheet 2.  What is it?  General, Text, something else?  Also, are all the cells with values on Worksheet 2 the same format?

3) What is the formula in the column of cells on Worksheet 1, which references Worksheet 2?  I presume it looks something like this `=Sheet2!A1`.  How did you copy the formula to the other cells in the column?

4) Is the list of values that you're attempting to Sum fairly short, like ten values or less?  If so, post them.

5) Try selecting the column in Worksheet 1 and looking at the results of Functions Excel offers on the Status Bar (Average, Count, Numerical Count, Min, Max, Sum)--assuming your version of Excel has this.

Comment: Thanks, I think this graphic of the sheets and data answer your questions. Thanks!: http://imgur.com/gallery/aTXl8MJ

Comment: Per my item 5, what are the values for Average, Count, Numerical Count, Min, Max, Sum when you select D10 through D12 of Sheet 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this issue by add 0 at the end of those cells that you get linked from other sheets. like =(Sheet2!A1)+0. This will make the cell a numeric format. Now you can add these cell data easily.